# Facebook API limitations

Tags: api, facebook

I was wondering what are Facebook limitations. My client wants such project:

> App allows user to post photo on their facebook page and share it with their friends with a message.

Can Facebook API allow all these steps to be accomplished?

Comment: I'm quite certain that there is no function in the Facebook API to merge the face of a user with a picture of a monkey.

Comment: I was more concerned about the #3 task.

Comment: @FacticiusVir Funny how things changed since 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, API provides it via `REST`:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/photos.upload - to upload a photo
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish - to publish it on the user's wall

Or the same with `Graph`:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post

Comment: Can I use IFRAME integration or XFBML is sufficient?

Comment: Sure, you are free to choose any canvas type you want.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook provides JS and other multiple SDKs for this, you can use the following js code for reference.

```
FB.api('/'+page_id+"/feed/", 'post',{"privacy":"{'value':'EVERYONE','description':'visible to everyone'}","access_token":access_token,
    message: title + " " + description,
    picture: image,
    from: 'me',
    caption: caption,
    link: photo_click_link,
    description: description
}, function(response) {
     if (!response || response.error) {
        access_token ="";
        get_access_token();
        show_custom_message(response["error"]);
    } else {
        update_ad_share_url_and_status(id, response.id,"page");
    }
});
```

where `page_id is the id of the page`

you can use the following privacy parameters to set privacy

```
When value is CUSTOM, this is a comma-separated list of user IDs and friend list IDs that can see the post. This can also be ALL_FRIENDS or FRIENDS_OF_FRIENDS to include all members of those sets.
```

Answer (score 0):

yes facebook api allow this , but your facebook app must take approval from facebook .
You must submit a request with your application details like website url and screen shoot after approval you are getting the public photos of your time line